# Proving $\forall x[p\vee\Phi(x)]\Longleftrightarrow [p\vee\forall x[\Phi(x)]$, where $p$ does not contain $x$ as a free variable

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

> How to prove this formula?
> $$\forall x[p\vee\Phi(x)]\;\Longleftrightarrow\; [p\vee\forall x[\Phi(x)]$$ where $p$ does not contain $x$ as a free variable.

I was reading Set theory by K. Kuratowski, A. Mostowski when I encountered this formula. The book says that it's easy to check. Well, I can prove the left arrow:

\begin{align}
[p\vee\forall x[\Phi(x)] &\Longleftrightarrow[\forall xp\vee \forall x[\Phi(x)] &&
(\forall xp\Longleftrightarrow p)\\
[\forall xp\vee\forall [\Phi(x)] & \implies \forall x[p\vee\Phi(x)] &&([\forall x\Phi(x)\vee\forall x\Psi(x)]\Rightarrow \forall x[\Phi(x)\vee\Psi(x)])
\end{align}

But I haven't got any idea how to prove the right arrow. I know an informal 'proof' using the fact that  if a,b,c,... denote the objects in my domain then

$∀xP(x)≈P(a)∧P(b)∧P(c)∧...$

$∃xP(x)≈P(a)∨P(b)∨P(c)∨...$

But I think that's not what the book suppose. How to prove the right arrow?

Comment: I would like to prove it syntactically.

Comment: You may convert disjunction to implication and employ the axiom: ∀x(A → B) → (A → ∀xB), where x does not occur free in A.

Comment: @TankutBeygu
Thank you, it worked. The funny thing is, the authors prove a stronger version of the axiom on the same page using the formula we're trying to prove, namely:

$[p\Rightarrow\forall x\Phi(x)]\Longleftrightarrow\forall x[p\Rightarrow\Phi(x)]$

Comment: @Physor
Perhaps I should have provided more details. I'll list all the formulas which we presume to be known at this point:

$\forall x[\Phi(x)\wedge\Psi(x)]\iff[\forall x[\Phi(x)\wedge\forall x\Psi(x)]$

$\exists x[\Phi(x)\vee\Psi(x)\iff[\exists x\Phi(x)\vee\exists x\Psi(x)]$

$\exists x[\Phi(x)\wedge\Psi(x)]\implies[\exists x\Phi(x)\wedge\exists x\Psi(x)]$

$\neg[\forall x[\Phi(x)]\iff\exists x[\neg\Phi(x)]$

$\neg[\exists x[\Phi(x)]\iff\forall x[\neg\Phi(x)]$

Comment: Could you mention the name of the book and the page

Comment: @Physor (1968) Set theory by K. Kuratowski, A. Mostowski p.48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your above effort is almost done to prove the equivalence for both directions, you only need to additionally realize $\forall xp\vee\forall \Phi(x) \implies \forall x[p\vee\Phi(x)]$ actually can be strengthened to $\forall xp\vee\forall \Phi(x) \Longleftrightarrow \forall x[p\vee\Phi(x)]$ when $p$ has no free occurrence of $x$. Also note in FOL the above equivalence with disjunction form doesn't hold in general, but its conjunction form always holds.

When formula $p$ has no free occurrence of $x$, $\forall x[p\vee\Phi(x)]$ is true if $p$ is true (which doesn't depend on $x$), or if $\forall x \Phi(x)$ is true, or both are true. So it's easy to check that this imposes the same *truth conditions* on both $p\vee\forall \Phi(x)$ and $\forall xp\vee\forall \Phi(x)$. Formally you can use $\forall$-elim, $\lor$-elim, and $\forall$-intro rules to syntactically derive if you can use a natural deduction system or similar rules in a Hilbert system.